# Website move: how to block/detect all HTTP requests to old domain

Tags: migration, xss, hotlinking

I'm moving a website from `old.com` to `new.com/old`, but I have to make sure it works before deleting `old.com`.

It's a very large legacy website that probably has links, images, scripts and other things hardcoded to `old.com`. The problem is that these references to `old.com` aren't obvious since the site loads up perfectly since `old.com` is still up.

Is there a way to block all requests to `old.com` from my local machine only, or some other tool to make finding these references simpler?

Answer (score 0):

The former is done by updating your hosts file on your local machine to point old.com to something else, this overrides what the internet DNS states.  The latter very much depends on how your application is build and there is not enough info here.